# Kerberos on Squid Server and Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, kerberos, squid

I have successfully run Active Directory and Squid Proxy (v.2.7) on our network. I wanted to give uniformed access to users on different departments so I wanted to make use of Kerberos for Squid to know what permission it should give to users knowing the Group it is assigned to the AD.

On the process of installing Kerberos inside the Squid Proxy Server (VM), I am stuck with an error when I tried to run msktutil. See below.

Can someone please explain to me what is the issue all about? And how do I start doing troubleshooting. I have research this matter in Google but getting vague responses.

```
root@debian:~# msktutil -c -b "CN-COMPUTERS" -s HTTP/debian.internal.local -k /etc/squid/PROXY.keytab --computer-name SQUIDPROXY --upn HTTP/debian.internal.local --server internal.servers.com.com --verbose
 -- init_password: Wiping the computer password structure
 -- create_fake_krb5_conf: Created a fake krb5.conf file: /tmp/.msktkrb5.conf-oyfv6j
 -- reload: Reloading Kerberos Context
 -- finalize_exec: SAM Account Name is: SQUIDPROXY$
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Trying to authenticate for SQUIDPROXY$ from local keytab...
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Error: krb5_get_init_creds_keytab failed (Client not found in Kerberos database)
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Authentication with keytab failed
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Trying to authenticate for host/debian.internal from local keytab...
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Error: krb5_get_init_creds_keytab failed (Client not found in Kerberos database)
 -- try_machine_keytab_princ: Authentication with keytab failed
 -- try_machine_password: Trying to authenticate for SQUIDPROXY$ with password.
 -- try_machine_password: Error: krb5_get_init_creds_keytab failed (Client not found in Kerberos database)
 -- try_machine_password: Authentication with password failed
 -- try_user_creds: Checking if default ticket cache has tickets...
 -- finalize_exec: Authenticated using method 4
 -- ldap_connect: Connecting to LDAP server: internal.servers.com.com try_tls=YES
 -- ldap_connect: Connecting to LDAP server: internal.servers.com.com try_tls=NO
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
Error: ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s failed (Local error)
Error: ldap_connect failed
--> Is your kerberos ticket expired? You might try re-"kinit"ing.
 -- ~KRB5Context: Destroying Kerberos Context
```

Also, this might give you more information what the problem is.

```
root@debian:~# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user@INTERNAL.SERVERS.COM.COM

Valid starting    Expires           Service principal
18/12/2014 00:23  18/12/2014 10:23  krbtgt/INTERNAL.SERVERS.COM.COM@INTERNAL.SERVERS.COM.COM
        renew until 19/12/2014 00:23
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long research. I found 2 points of failure for getting this error.

1. On the host file, the realm was specified but kerberos was not about to resolve it.
   Adding another value (dc1.myexchange.com) of the realm (myexchange.com) seem to enable the connection between the AD and Squid Server (where kerberos is running).
2. Assumption. Since I was able to kinit I assumed that the AD can see the query from the squid server. So, I was not able to check the DNS between the two servers.

Comment: Could you specify what files and/or commands you edited/run to solve the issue?

Comment: This specifically falls on the DNS for both machines. That's the only way they can establish two way connection (so they can see each other). Make sure both machine's DNS settings are the same